# where should I put json data inside android

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am planning to store some data in `json` in that way I can read and write this `json` data.
I want to use it as a simple database instead of using `sqlite`.

Where should I create this `json` data in file hierarchy and how to write and read data from `json`.

Answer (score 0):

just declare a string variable and then set that to your json like :

```
String myjson = "obj1: {}..."  //it is your json

JsonObject obj = new JsonObject(myJson);
```

then you can do

```
String s = obj.getString("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very nice question for a beginner in Android so I will tell you about singleton class which we use to store data in any language.

"Singleton class" this is a class which have only one reference (object). Code how to make this class is below:

```
public class DataController {

    private static DataController ref;

    public static DataController getInstance()
    {
        if(ref==null)
            ref = new DataController();

        return ref;
    }

    public void deleteInstance()
    {
        ref=null;
    }
    public ArrayList<MediaWrapper>videoWrapper = new ArrayList<MediaWrapper>();
    public ArrayList<MediaWrapper>audioWrapper = new ArrayList<MediaWrapper>();
    public ArrayList<MediaWrapper>documentWrapper = new ArrayList<MediaWrapper>();
}// you can add any data type under this class
```

Now anywhere you can use this class like this put this code inside your activity on-create method where you want to use this.

```
private DataController controller;
    controller = DataController.getInstance();
```

Now just call that datatype in which you want to add your data like this.

`controller.videoWrapper` = //put your data inside this. This data will be save until or unless your activity in the stack

Also you can access that data like this `controller.videoWrapper` it will give you all data which you save in this.

Comment: always welcome dude nd use this singleton class always because this is my besty class in java and i use most of time in my code